# How do I change the file name before sending it to Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration to do a file polling on a directory. But I want to append the time stamp on the file name before anything is done to it and sent to spring batch.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Basically you want to configure an input channel, a processor/handler and an output channel. The input represents the input files. The processor/handler renames the files and the output moves this to the output directory for spring batch.

Using the [spring-integration-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) as my reference (and worth checking out anyway):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

    <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                                  directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/input">
        <integration:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <integration:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                                   output-channel="filesOut"
                                   ref="handler"/>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"
                                   directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>

    <bean id="handler" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.filecopy.Handler"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: This seems to work half way for me. The batch job is launched with the new file name, but the reader gets the old file name. Because of that, I get resource must exist.

Comment: @samwell ... silly question ... but is the reader perhaps looking at the wrong folder? ... I can't see your batch config so I have to assume things :)

Comment: Wow yea I had it set to look at a pre-defined file. Though when I change it to "file://#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}", I'm having issues, I'll make another post about it, I don't think it pertains to this post.

Answer (score 3):

Sample below created with the help of one of the Spring Integration [samples on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/file/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/fileCopyDemo-text.xml).

Here's the same sample, modified to demonstrate the timestamp being added to the output file name:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                              directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/input"
                              filename-regex="[a-z]+.txt">
    <integration:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="strings"/>

<integration:channel id="strings"/>

<integration:service-activator input-channel="strings"
                               output-channel="filesOut"
                               ref="handler"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output"
     filename-generator-expression="new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.' + headers['file_name']" />

<bean id="handler" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.filecopy.Handler"/>
```

The most relevant part from the code above is this: `filename-generator-expression="new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.' + headers['file_name']"` which shows that with a simple SpEL expression your output file has the desired name.

Comment: Thanks, I also posted this below, but this seems to work half way for me. The batch job is launched with the new file name, but the reader gets the old file name. Because of that, I get resource must exist.

Comment: You asked a simple question about changing file names in Spring Integration without any other details about the configuration. My attempt for a solution assumed several things. It is impossible to offer further suggestions without any other details.